# Very complex structuration of a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

please take a look of this query:

```
SELECT DATE(datetime), COUNT(1) as numVisits 
FROM ".table_stats." 
WHERE type='profile_visit' 
    AND user_url = '".$_GET['ref']."' 
    AND id_user='".$_SESSION['user_code']."' 
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(datetime, INTERVAL 1 DAY))
```

---

This query counts the number of times that *type* is equal to 'profile_visit' by each date, as a result it gives me two rows (DATE(datetime), numVisits). This is a screen capture of the table table_stats:
[image: Table 1]
**Table_Stats**

---

Ok, until now you can understand that every time a user comes to the site a new element is inserted on the table with **type**=profile_visit and the **datetime** field with the date and time of the visit, thats why i use a *GROUP BY DATE(datetime)* to count the total number of visits by day.

Here comes the complex part, when the *type* field is equal to 'click' and the *origin* is 'imp' that means that a user hits a particular button on the page, i will like to know how many times that button was clicked (no matter the ip) by day, just like i did with the profile visits.

I can make two querys, one to know the total visits (like the one before) and another similar just by grouping by *datetime* when *type* is 'click' and *origin* is 'imp'.

The problem is that i will like to make this just in one call in order to count the total visits by date in the row NumVisits like i did before and a new row call NumClick with the total of clicks made. This is why i dont want more calculations on my php server, if its possible will be great to make all the calculation on the sql server.

So finally, if you call this query to the table:

```
SELECT DATE( DATETIME ) , COUNT( 1 ) AS numVisits
FROM stats_ram
WHERE TYPE =  'profile_visit'
AND user_url =  'xxx'
AND id_user =  '88e91'
GROUP BY DATE( DATE_SUB( DATETIME, INTERVAL 1 
DAY ) ) 
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

You will get:

```
DATE(datetime)  numVisits
2011-11-16      7
```

**How can i add another row with the total type=click AND origin=imp made by DATE(datetime)???**

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: First things first, please don't use $_GET directly in your SQL...

Comment: dont worry about security matters this is just an example

Comment: @DomingoSL: interpolating `$_GET` directly into the statement suggests there are other issues with the code, such as the fact you're interpolating values at all rather than using a prepared statement.

Comment: `$ref = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ref']); ... $sql = ".... AND user_url = '$ref' ...";`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DATE(DATETIME), 
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'profile_visit' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS numVisits,
    SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'click' AND origin = 'imp' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) numClicks
FROM stats_ram
WHERE user_url = 'xxx'
    AND id_user = '88e91'
GROUP BY DATE(DATE_SUB(DATETIME, INTERVAL 1 DAY)) 
LIMIT 0, 30
```